# snap package nano-editor not visible on ubuntu core

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, raspberrypi, nano

I have installed:

```
OS: Ubuntu Core 16 
image: (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1030-raspi2 armv7l)
HW: RASPBERRY PI 3 MODEL B
```

and I want to install nano

however I can not find it using:

```
snap find nano-editor
```

I know the package is available because on:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
HW: Assus Laptop
```

I can find the package with the command:

> snap find nano-editor

```
Name              Version      Developer             Notes  Summary
nano-editor       2.6.3        rws                   -      The nano text editor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the nano-editor package uploaded by rws was only built for amd64 architecture, and not the arm based arch the pi uses.

I emailed the maintainer of the package and asked them to upload an arm build too.

Comment: Seem that even some (almost) 2 years later that the armhf architecture is still no available. :(

Answer (score 4):

Run `snap install pinano` to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be better if you explained why this is a solution.